# simulating drag using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, drag, monkeyrunner

I have android ics-x86 and i need to simulate drag event but device.drag is giving error
it is giving me class cast exception.i have called it like this-

```
      x=(67.8,100.0)
      y=(267.8,100.0)
      device.drag(x,y,10.0,10)
```

what is  wrong with the arguments??please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

device.drag (tuple start, tuple end, float duration, integer steps)

example: device.drag((350, 620), (13, 620), 0.5, 50)

Comment: What are "duration" and "steps"? I presume duration of .5 means .5 seconds to execute the drag? What does the 50 steps mean? (is there any documentation for this stuff anywhere? thanks =)